# Jquery dropdown menu is covered by a frame on a webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm using a using this [jquery dropdown menu](http://javascript-array.com/data/scripts/simple_drop_down_menu/dropdownmenu.zip) in my banner frame (mail_frame.html). when it drops down it gets covered by another frame that's below it. even though i set the z-index of the drop down to 999 in it's css, it's still behind the other frame

**frameset.jsp**

```
</head>
    <frameset id="frameMain" rows="84,*" framespacing="0">
       <frame src="mail_frame.html" id="mail" name="mail" frameborder="0" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no"/>
       <frameset id="frameSet" cols="126,*" framespacing="0">
           <frame src="leftNavigation.do?loadWelcome=true<%= currentURL %>" id="leftnav" name="leftnav" frameborder="0" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no"/>
           <frame src="empty.htm" id="main" name="main" frameborder="0" border="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="yes"/>
       </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

how can i make it drop down on top of everything

Answer (score 1):

Classic frames (what you're using) are completely independent windows. You can't have an element in one frame that then extends over the content of another frame. You *can* do that with iframes, but not with the kind you're using.

It may be time to consider moving to a frameless layout, as that's the direction the technology seems to be going. For instance, [neither `frame` nor `frameset` is part of HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#absent-elements). As an alternative, you can use [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) (an increasingly outdated name, as I suspect most people are using it with [JSON](http://json.org) instead of XML now) to update individual elements within a page.

Comment: Building on that, if you want to just refresh portions of your page then consider ajax/json requests to update specific potions

Comment: @Hawxby: Yeah, I reworded the end of the last sentence because it looked like I was recommending replacing frames with iframes, which wasn't my intent. There are certainly times when iframes are the right answer, but by and large, not usually.

Comment: I dont know what all this means to be honest. is there any other way that you can think of to do it with the frameset ive got. popup or something similar

Comment: @Dave819: Each classic frame (the kind you're using) is a DOM "window", and the elements within that window can't extend outside of it and be visible. They just can't, it's a fundamental limitation. Yes, you could pop up a completely separate browser window, but that's not likely to work well (not least because a lot of browsers will open that window in a tab instead, which *really* isn't what you want). I'm afraid that your current structure is not compatible with this drop-down menu. No offense intended, but it sounds like you may need to bring in some help on this.